# d3 force not applying x scale properly

Tags: d3.js, d3-force-directed

I want to apply a scale to circles generated with d3 force from an array.

This code produces the right x axis, but there are loads of circles produced with the class 'goalamount' and they are all offscreen by tens of thousands of pixels. There should only be six circles in the goalamount class and they should all scale to the xaxis - what am I doing wrong?

```js
const data = [{
    x: 2020,
    cx: 0,
    colour: "#69306D",
    scY: 0,
    y2: 50,
    rad: 10,
    amt: 5000
  },
  {
    x: 2020,
    cx: 0,
    colour: "#247BA0",
    scY: 0,
    y2: 50,
    rad: 10,
    amt: 5000
  },
  {
    x: 2020,
    cx: 0,
    colour: "#3F762C",
    y1: 0,
    y2: 50,
    rad: 10,
    amt: 5000
  },
  {
    x: 2020,
    cx: 0,
    colour: "#F25F5C",
    y1: 0,
    y2: 50,
    rad: 10,
    amt: 5000
  },
  {
    x: 2022,
    cx: 0,
    colour: "#0C3957",
    y1: 0,
    y2: 170,
    rad: 10,
    amt: 5000
  },
  {
    x: 2055,
    cx: 0,
    colour: "#BF802F",
    y1: 0,
    y2: 50,
    rad: 10,
    amt: 15000
  }
];

const maxYear = Math.max.apply(Math, data.map(function(o) {
  return o.x;
}));

const svg = d3.select("svg");
const pxX = svg.attr("width");
const pxY = svg.attr("height");
let tickLabelOffset = 170;

let minDotX = Math.min.apply(Math, data.map(function(o) {
  return o.y1;
}))
if (minDotX < -20) {
  tickLabelOffset += minDotX + 20;
}

const makeScale = (arr, accessor, range) => {
  return d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(arr, accessor))
    .range(range)
    .nice()
}

const thisYear = new Date().getFullYear()

let tickTens = [];
for (let i = thisYear; i < maxYear; i++) {
  if (i % 10 === 0) {
    tickTens.push(i)
  }
}


const scX = makeScale(data, d => d.x, [0, pxX - 200]);
const scX1 = makeScale(data, d => d.x, [0, pxX - 2020]);
const scY = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range([0, 100]);

const g = d3.axisBottom(scX).tickValues(
  tickTens.map((tickVal) => {
    return tickVal
  })
)

const rad = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.rad))
  .range([3, 10]);

const amt = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.amt))
  .range([20, 50]);

for (let dotindex = 0; dotindex < data.length; dotindex++) {
  if (data[dotindex - 1]) {
    if (data[dotindex - 1].x === data[dotindex].x) {
      data[dotindex].scY = data[dotindex - 1].scY - 20
    }
  }
}

const ticked = () => {
  var u = d3.select('svg')
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "goalAmounts")
    .selectAll('goalAmounts')
    .data(data)

  u.enter()
    .append("circle")
    // .attr( "transform", "translate(" + 2000 + "," + 50 + ")")
    .attr("r", d => amt(d.amt))
    .merge(u)
    .attr("fill", d => d.colour)
    .attr("cx", d => scX(d.x))
    .attr("cy", d => scY(d.y2))

  u.exit().remove()
}


svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 50 + "," + (pxY - 200) + ")")
  .call(g)
  .selectAll(".tick text")
  .attr("fill", "#7A7A7A")

svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "circles")
  .append("circle")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 100 + "," + 650 + ")")
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .attr("stroke", d => d.colour)
  .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
  .attr("cx", d => scX(d.x))
  .attr("cy", d => scY(d.y2))
  .attr("r", d => rad(d.rad));

svg.selectAll(".domain")
  .attr("stroke", "#BDBDBD")
  .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 50 + "," + 150 + ")")

svg.selectAll(".tick line")
  .attr("stroke", "#BDBDBD")
  .attr("stroke-width", "4px")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 50 + "," + 150 + ")")

svg.selectAll(".tick text")
  .attr("font-size", 20)
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 50 + "," + tickLabelOffset + ")")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold")
  .attr("dy", "0.5em")

d3.forceSimulation(data)
  .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())
  .force('center', d3.forceCenter(pxX / 2, pxY / 2))
  .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) {
    return d.amt
  }))
  .on('tick', ticked);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="App">
  <svg id="demo1" width="1200" height="700">
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `d3.forceX` and `d3.forceY` instead, so you draw the nodes towards their intended position. Also, `d3-force` populates `x` and `y` properties of the nodes, so you need to use `d.x1` or something instead. `scX(d.x)` caused the huge values of the nodes.

```js
const data = [{
    x1: 2020,
    cx: 0,
    colour: "#69306D",
    scY: 0,
    y2: 50,
    rad: 10,
    amt: 5000
  },
  {
    x1: 2020,
    cx: 0,
    colour: "#247BA0",
    scY: 0,
    y2: 50,
    rad: 10,
    amt: 5000
  },
  {
    x1: 2020,
    cx: 0,
    colour: "#3F762C",
    y1: 0,
    y2: 50,
    rad: 10,
    amt: 5000
  },
  {
    x1: 2020,
    cx: 0,
    colour: "#F25F5C",
    y1: 0,
    y2: 50,
    rad: 10,
    amt: 5000
  },
  {
    x1: 2022,
    cx: 0,
    colour: "#0C3957",
    y1: 0,
    y2: 170,
    rad: 10,
    amt: 5000
  },
  {
    x1: 2055,
    cx: 0,
    colour: "#BF802F",
    y1: 0,
    y2: 50,
    rad: 10,
    amt: 15000
  }
];

const maxYear = Math.max.apply(Math, data.map(function(o) {
  return o.x1;
}));

const svg = d3.select("svg");
const pxX = svg.attr("width");
const pxY = svg.attr("height");
let tickLabelOffset = 170;

let minDotX = Math.min.apply(Math, data.map(function(o) {
  return o.y1;
}))
if (minDotX < -20) {
  tickLabelOffset += minDotX + 20;
}

const makeScale = (arr, accessor, range) => {
  return d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(arr, accessor))
    .range(range)
    .nice()
}

const thisYear = new Date().getFullYear()

let tickTens = [];
for (let i = thisYear; i < maxYear; i++) {
  if (i % 10 === 0) {
    tickTens.push(i)
  }
}

const scX = makeScale(data, d => d.x1, [0, pxX - 200]);
const scX1 = makeScale(data, d => d.x1, [0, pxX - 2020]);
const scY = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range([0, 100]);

const g = d3.axisBottom(scX).tickValues(
  tickTens.map((tickVal) => {
    return tickVal
  })
)

const rad = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.rad))
  .range([3, 10]);

const amt = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.amt))
  .range([20, 50]);

for (let dotindex = 0; dotindex < data.length; dotindex++) {
  if (data[dotindex - 1]) {
    if (data[dotindex - 1].x1 === data[dotindex].x1) {
      data[dotindex].scY = data[dotindex - 1].scY - 20
    }
  }
}

const ticked = () => {
  circles
    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y);
}


svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 50 + "," + (pxY - 200) + ")")
  .call(g)
  .selectAll(".tick text")
  .attr("fill", "#7A7A7A")

const circles = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "circles")
  .attr( "transform", "translate(" + 100 + "," + 100 + ")")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .attr("stroke", d => d.colour)
  .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
  .attr("cx", d => scX(d.x1))
  .attr("cy", d => scY(d.y2))
  .attr("r", d => rad(d.rad));

svg.selectAll(".domain")
  .attr("stroke", "#BDBDBD")
  .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 50 + "," + 150 + ")")

svg.selectAll(".tick line")
  .attr("stroke", "#BDBDBD")
  .attr("stroke-width", "4px")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 50 + "," + 150 + ")")

svg.selectAll(".tick text")
  .attr("font-size", 20)
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 50 + "," + tickLabelOffset + ")")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold")
  .attr("dy", "0.5em")

d3.forceSimulation(data)
  .force("x", d3.forceX(d => scX(d.x1)))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(d => scY(d.y2)))
  .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(d => rad(d.rad)))
  .on("tick", ticked);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="App">
  <svg id="demo1" width="1200" height="700">
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great - got it working now! The last thing I don't understand is forcing the cx of the circles towards the approximate positions in my value at d.x - this code seems to do something, but not exactly what I need .force("x", scX(d3.forceX(d => (d.x))))

Comment: I do that in the last few lines of JavaScript

Comment: Yeah but it doesn't seem to work very well? I'm trying to anchor the circles to the x coords - so if a circle has x coord 2031 it stays close to it?

Comment: It should already do that. Did you see that I changed `d.x` to `d.x1`? Also, your translation was really weird, so maybe that's the reason. Why even do a translation like that with hardcoded values?

Comment: I take your points and I'm still pretty stuck - if you would take a look at my repo, the src is just the App.js file https://github.com/DavTho1983/d3-examples