# d3 forceX not positioning circles near their x axis value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

My d3 graph is looking great - it's beautiful apart from one thing - the x position of my circles does not seem to correspond very closely with the x values given in my array.

I have an array of objects which are like this:

```
  {
      x: 2020,
      cx: 0,
      colour: "#F25F5C",
      y1: 0,
      y2: 200,
      rad: 10,
      amt: 5000
    },
```

I have two sets of circles. The first is positioned really close to the xaxis and indicates an exact date, and their colours match those of larger circles, whose radii vary across a larger scale and I apply d3.force to these to position them more effectively.

The trouble is that the larger circles should be positioned with their centres close to values in the array given by (x, y2). They are not though, and my forceX doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my complete code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [maxYear, setMaxYear] = useState();
  const [data, setData] = useState(
   [{
      x: 2020,
      colour: "#69306D",
      y1: 0,
      y2: 50,
      rad: 10,
      amt: 2000
    },
    {
      x: 2020,
      colour: "#247BA0",
      y1: 0,
      y2: 100,
      rad: 10,
      amt: 5000
    },
    {
      x: 2020,
      colour: "#3F762C",
      y1: 0,
      y2: 150,
      rad: 10,
      amt: 7500
    },
    {
      x: 2020,
      colour: "#F25F5C",
      y1: 0,
      y2: 200,
      rad: 10,
      amt: 5000
    },
    {
      x: 2022,
      colour: "#0C3957",
      y1: 0,
      y2: 250,
      rad: 10,
      amt: 9000
    },
    {
      x: 2055,
      colour: "#BF802F",
      y1: 0,
      y2: 300,
      rad: 10,
      amt: 25000
    }
  ]
  );

  const thisYear = new Date().getFullYear()

  const initialiseData = () => {
    const svg = d3.select( "svg" );
    const pxX = svg.attr( "width" );
    const pxY = svg.attr( "height" );
    let tickLabelOffset = 170;
    
    let minDotX = Math.min.apply(Math, data.map(function(o) { return o.y1; }))
    if (minDotX < -20) {
      tickLabelOffset += minDotX + 20;
    }

    const makeScale = ( arr, accessor, range ) => {
      // console.log("RANGE", accessor, range)
      return d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain( d3.extent( arr, accessor ) )
        .range( range )
        .nice()
    }

    //SCALES//
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    const scX = makeScale( data, d => d.x, [0, pxX - 200]);
    const scY = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range( [0, 100] );

    const rad = d3.scaleLinear() //scale for radius of small dots on xaxis
      .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.rad))
      .range([3, 10]);
    
    const amt = d3.scaleLinear() //scale for radius of large circle      .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.amt))
      .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.amt))
      .range([20, 150]);
    
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    //END OF SCALES//
    
    //stacks small dots on x axis
    for (let dotindex=0; dotindex<data.length; dotindex++) {
      if (data[dotindex - 1]) {
        if (data[dotindex - 1].x === data[dotindex].x) {
          data[dotindex].y1 = data[dotindex -1].y1 -20
        }
      }
    }

    //creates array of multiples of ten for x axis labels
    let tickTens = [];
    for (let i=thisYear; i<maxYear; i++) {
      if (i % 10 === 0) {
        tickTens.push(i)
      }
    }
    
    //maps array of multiples of ten to values at ticks on x axis
    const g = d3.axisBottom( scX ).tickValues(
      tickTens.map((tickVal) => {
        return tickVal
      })
    )

      //Groups data into arrays by goal year
      const _data = data.reduce(
          (r, v, _, __, k = v["x"]) => ((r[k] || (r[k] = [])).push(v), r),
          []
        )

      //CREATE X AXIS//
      //---------------------------------------------------------------------------//

      svg.append( "g" )
      .attr( "transform", "translate(" + 50 + "," + (pxY - 200) + ")")
      .call( g )
      .selectAll(".tick text")
      .attr("fill", "#7A7A7A")

      svg.selectAll(".domain")
      .attr("stroke", "#BDBDBD")
      .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
      .attr( "transform", "translate(" + 50 + "," + 150 + ")")

      svg.selectAll(".tick line")
      .attr("stroke", "#BDBDBD")
      .attr("stroke-width", "4px")
      .attr( "transform", "translate(" + 50 + "," + 150 + ")")
        
      svg.selectAll( ".tick text")
        .attr("font-size", 20)
        .attr( "transform", "translate(" + 50 + "," + tickLabelOffset + ")")
        .attr("font-weight", "bold")
        .attr("dy", "0.5em")

      svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "circles")
        .append("circle")
        .attr( "transform", "translate(" + 100 + "," + 650 + ")")
        .attr("fill", "white")
        .attr("stroke", d => d.colour)
        .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
        .attr("cx", d => scX(d.x))
        .attr("cy", d => scY(d.y1))
        .attr("r", d => rad(d.rad));

      //END OF CREATE X AXIS//
      //---------------------------------------------------------------------------//


      //CREATE LARGE CIRCLES//
      //---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
      const ticked = () => {
        goalAmounts
          .attr("cx", (d => (2 * d.x)))
          .attr("cy", d => d.y2);
      }

      let i = 0;

      const goalAmounts = svg.selectAll("circle .circles")
        .append( "g" )
        .attr("class", "goalAmounts")
        .data(data.sort(function(a, b) {
          return a.amt - b.amt;
      }).reverse())
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr( "transform", "translate(" + 650 + "," + 0 + ")")
        .attr("fill", d => {
          return d.colour}
        )
        .attr("cx", d => (d.x))
        .attr("cy", (d, index) => {
          let _y = scY(d.y2)
          if (_data[d.x].length > 1 && _data[i-1]) {
            i++
            _y =  _data[d.x][i -1].y2
          } else {
            i = 0
          }
          return _y
        })
        .attr("r", d => amt(d.amt));

      d3.forceSimulation(data)
      // .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-200))
      .force('x', scX(d3.forceX().x(function(d) {
        return d.x
      })))
      .force("y", d3.forceY(d => (d.y2 * Math.random())))
      .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(d => amt(d.amt/2)))
      .on("tick", ticked);

    //END OF CREATE LARGE CIRCLES//
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
      
  }

  

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setMaxYear(Math.max.apply(Math, data.map(function(o) { return o.x; })))
    }

    if (maxYear) {
      initialiseData();
    }

  }, [data,maxYear])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <svg id="demo1" width="1200" height="700" style={{background: "white"}}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Please see how the code works so far with this sandbox: [d3Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-thunder-3l7ok?file=/src/App.css)

Comment: 1. Your codesandbox is full of errors, it's not working. 2. As I explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64527212/5015356), you need to rename `x` to `x1` or something, because `d.x` is overridden by `d3-force` and set to a value in pixels, not in years like you seem to want

Comment: like this? x1: 2020

Comment: Yes, exactly. Have another look at the answer and check specifically where I use `d.x1` and where I use `d.x`. Note that I never use `d.x` together with `scX`!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for a working version I think?

```
 import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [maxYear, setMaxYear] = useState();
  const [data, setData] = useState(
   [{
      x1: 2020,
      colour: "#69306D",
      y1: 0,
      y2: 50,
      rad: 10,
      amt: 2000
    },
    {
      x1: 2021,
      colour: "#247BA0",
      y1: 0,
      y2: 100,
      rad: 10,
      amt: 5000
    },
    {
      x1: 2030,
      colour: "#3F762C",
      y1: 0,
      y2: 150,
      rad: 10,
      amt: 7500
    },
    {
      x1: 2020,
      colour: "#F25F5C",
      y1: 0,
      y2: 200,
      rad: 10,
      amt: 5000
    },
    {
      x1: 2022,
      colour: "#0C3957",
      y1: 0,
      y2: 250,
      rad: 10,
      amt: 9000
    },
    {
      x1: 2055,
      colour: "#BF802F",
      y1: 0,
      y2: 300,
      rad: 10,
      amt: 25000
    }
  ]
  );

  const thisYear = new Date().getFullYear()

  const initialiseData = () => {
    const svg = d3.select( "svg" );
    const pxX = svg.attr( "width" );
    const pxY = svg.attr( "height" );
    let tickLabelOffset = 170;
    
    let minDotX = Math.min.apply(Math, data.map(function(o) { return o.y1; }))
    if (minDotX < -20) {
      tickLabelOffset += minDotX + 20;
    }

    const makeScale = ( arr, accessor, range ) => {
      // console.log("RANGE", accessor, range)
      return d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain( d3.extent( arr, accessor ) )
        .range( range )
        .nice()
    }

    //SCALES//
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    const scX = makeScale( data, d => d.x1, [0, pxX - 200]);
    const scX2 = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([2020, 2080])
    .range( [0, pxX - 200] );
    const scY = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range( [0, 100] );

    const rad = d3.scaleLinear() //scale for radius of small dots on xaxis
      .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.rad))
      .range([3, 10]);
    
    const amt = d3.scaleLinear() //scale for radius of large circle      .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.amt))
      .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.amt))
      .range([20, 150]);
    
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
    //END OF SCALES//
    
    //stacks small dots on x axis
    let _newData = data;
    for (let dotindex=0; dotindex<data.length; dotindex++) {
      if (_newData[dotindex - 1]) {
        if (_newData[dotindex - 1].x1 === _newData[dotindex].x1) {
          _newData[dotindex].y1 = _newData[dotindex -1].y1 -20
        }
      }
    }

    setData(_newData)

    console.log("DATA: ", data)

    //creates array of multiples of ten for x axis labels
    let tickTens = [];
    for (let i=thisYear; i<maxYear; i++) {
      if (i % 10 === 0) {
        tickTens.push(i)
      }
    }
    
    //maps array of multiples of ten to values at ticks on x axis
    const g = d3.axisBottom( scX ).tickValues(
      tickTens.map((tickVal) => {
        return tickVal
      })
    )

      //Groups data into arrays by goal year
      const _data = data.reduce(
          (r, v, _, __, k = v["x"]) => ((r[k] || (r[k] = [])).push(v), r),
          []
        )

      //CREATE X AXIS//
      //---------------------------------------------------------------------------//

      svg.append( "g" )
      .attr( "transform", "translate(" + 50 + "," + (pxY - 200) + ")")
      .call( g )
      .selectAll(".tick text")
      .attr("fill", "#7A7A7A")

      svg.selectAll(".domain")
      .attr("stroke", "#BDBDBD")
      .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
      .attr( "transform", "translate(" + 50 + "," + 150 + ")")

      svg.selectAll(".tick line")
      .attr("stroke", "#BDBDBD")
      .attr("stroke-width", "4px")
      .attr( "transform", "translate(" + 50 + "," + 150 + ")")
        
      svg.selectAll( ".tick text")
        .attr("font-size", 20)
        .attr( "transform", "translate(" + 50 + "," + tickLabelOffset + ")")
        .attr("font-weight", "bold")
        .attr("dy", "0.5em")

      svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "xDots")
        .append("circle")
        .attr( "transform", "translate(" + 100 + "," + 650 + ")")
        .attr("fill", "white")
        .attr("stroke", d => d.colour)
        .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
        .attr("cx", d => scX(d.x1))
        .attr("cy", d => scY(d.y1))
        .attr("r", d => rad(d.rad));

      //END OF CREATE X AXIS//
      //---------------------------------------------------------------------------//


      //CREATE LARGE CIRCLES//
      //---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
      const ticked = () => {
        goalAmounts
          .attr("cx", (d => d.x))
          .attr("cy", d => d.y);
      }

      let i = 0;

      const goalAmounts = svg.selectAll()
        .data(data.sort(function(a, b) {
          return a.amt - b.amt;
      }).reverse())
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "goals")
        .append("circle")
        .attr( "transform", "translate(" + 200 + "," + 100 + ")")
        .attr("fill", d => {
          return d.colour}
        )
        .attr("cx", d => {
          // console.log("DX1, ", d.x1,  (d.x1)
          return d.x1
        })
        .attr("cy", (d, index) => {
          let _y = scY(d.y2)
      }
        )
        .attr("r", d => amt(d.amt));

      d3.forceSimulation(data)
      // .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-20))
      .force('x', (d3.forceX().x(function(d) {
        return scX2(d.x1)
      })))
      .force("y", d3.forceY(d => (d.y2 * Math.random())))
      .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(d => amt(d.amt) + 10))
      .on("tick", ticked);

    //END OF CREATE LARGE CIRCLES//
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------//
      
  }

  

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      console.log("DATA: ", data)
      setMaxYear(Math.max.apply(Math, data.map(function(o) { return o.x1; })))
    }

    if (maxYear) {
      console.log("MAXYEAR", maxYear)
      initialiseData();
    }

  }, [data, maxYear])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <svg id="demo1" width="1200" height="700" style={{background: "white"}}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Happy to see you figured it out!

Comment: I'm sincerely sorry I'm such a pain - I'm under a massive amount of pressure to learn this too quickly and I really appreciate your help

Comment: No worries, happy to help